# Running Quarkus with persistence extension using h2 database

Tags: quarkus

Dears,
I am trying to run [persistence guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-guide) by quarkus.io but using h2 server instead of postgresSql, now when i run mvn compile quarkus:dev, it compile then exists and give message build successfully without showing any debugging messages to know what happended !!!, how can trace my problem in this case ?

**Note** : i already configured logging for console and file but it no more shows any helpful messages after configuring JPA & Hibernate.

My Environment :
OS : CentOS 7, Java : 1.8.0_181, Maven : 3.5.4, Quarkus : 0.11.0

Regards.

Comment: Try adding this to your application.properties file: quarkus.hibernate.show-sql=true

Comment: I tried the above but with no results :( .

Answer (score 2):

I found this GitHub issue, so you are not the first: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1393.

In the meantime, try using "mvn package" and "java -jar target/*runner*".  Set quarkus.log.level=TRACE or DEBUG in application.properties, which will be picked up when running via java -jar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint John, it gave me a proper error message which is i forgot to annotate my service class with proper annotation (@ApplicationScoped/@RequestedScope), when i do package target it showed me the error nice and clean, we need to fix this in quarkus:dev, i will try to do a contribution on this area .

Comment: Another potential cause could be this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1363 which has been fixed and will not be an issue as of `0.12.0`